# Exporting German umlauts with PowerShell 3 by Out-File CMDlet

Tags: powershell, unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am currently facing a problem with the `Out-File` CMDlet which I use for creating a log file. This works fine at all, but unfortunately I can't force PowerShell to export the German umlauts correctly. What I tried was:

- saving the script file with UTF-8 encoding (I use Sublime Text as editor)
- appending an existing text file which I saved with MS Notepad before (`Out-File` CMDlet uses its `-Append` parameter in this case; otherwise a new file is created which has Unicode encoding if the `-Encoding` parameter is not set otherwise)
- using `"My String" | Out-File "xyz.log" -Encoding utf8` while the `-Encoding` parameter should handle the string export with UTF-8 encoding; specifying the value `utf8` of `-Encoding` with double quotation marks (`"My String" | Out-File "xyz.log" -Encoding "utf8"`) does not work as well

[Microsoft's Developer Network](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849882.aspx) and other threads on StackOverflow couldn't really solve my problem. Does anyone know a solution or at least a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Can't reproduce. `"äöü" | Out-File "xyz.log" -Encoding utf8` works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. During my research on this issue I found many other threads on several platforms where people facing this problem. Maybe there's some global encoding parameter in PowerShell or any other configuration which is not correct in my case.

Comment: You need to save the file in UTF8 [WITH the BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64440598/powershell-umlaute-check-shows-always-false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for my issue much faster than I thought before. What I did is to replace each umlaut in a logging string with its Unicode value. For that I created an array `$umlauts` of arrays containing the particular umlaut with its unicode value.

What you should also focus on is to wrap your logging string into **single** quotation marks (`'äöü'`) due to the fact that PowerShell seems to have problems with umlauts and double quotation marks (`"äöü"`).

**UPDATE 1:** As mentioned by [n3wjack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122983/n3wjack), a string with umlauts has to be wrapped in single quotation marks so that PowerShell will handle every character "as it is".

Here is my implementation for what I described above:

```
function Out-LogFile ($str) {
    $umlauts = @(
        @('Ä',[char]0x00C4),
        @('Ö',[char]0x00D6),
        @('Ü',[char]0x00DC),
        @('ä',[char]0x00E4),
        @('ö',[char]0x00F6),
        @('ü',[char]0x00FC)
    )

    foreach ($umlaut in $umlauts) {
        $str = $str -replace $umlaut[0],$umlaut[1]
    }

    $str | Out-File "myfile.txt"
    return $str
}

Out-LogFile 'ÄÖÜäöü'
```

**UPDATE 2:** I noticed that n3wjack's tip makes my implementation obsolete. By just wrapping the log text into single quoatation marks (like `'äöü' | Out-File "file.log"`) all umlauts are exported correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Strange. This seems to work fine for me. Anyway, there is a difference in how PS handles single and double quotes. It will leave a string enclosed in single quotes as is. For a string in double quotes, it will check if it needs to do any variable replacements, e;g. "Hello $name", where $name is your variable to replace. If you have the same string in single quotes, it will output it as a literal.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and your tip concerning the quotation marks. I will add this to my explaination.