# Powershell Umlaute check shows always false

Tags: powershell

This code

```
$text = "Überflieger"
$text.ToLower()
if($text.ToLower().Contains('ü')) {
    Write-Host 'True'
} else {
    Write-Host 'False'
}
```

shows as result

```
ãœberflieger
False
```

which is wrong.
The source is a CSV. Therefore it can be not guaranteed letters are UTF8 encoded. How to properly check german umlaute with powershell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those having that problem also.
With a lot of search (and help from Microsoft) I found this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/vscode/understanding-file-encoding?view=powershell-5.1

It explains a lot about the encoding problem. So the solution is to store the script which does the Umlaute check in UTF8 WITH BOM